# Can I uses Salesforce1 Mobile Browser on Windows 8.1 tablet (11" screen)?

Tags: salesforce1-app, mobile, browser

We have purchased a heavy duty Windows 10 based tablet for warehouse use, but need Salesforce1 to be the user experience.  I have gone into settings and enabled the Salesforce1 mobile browser application, but it still doesn't render (goes to standard lightning).  Here are the browser versions i have tried:

IE 11
Chrome 56

Comment: Can you post the screenshot from chrome, do you have lightning enabled?

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce1 App for Windows is not yet GA. Most blogs refer to browser based SF1 as the salesforce App.

You can use the workaround or you can always emulate your user-agent to force salesforce to load SF1 app.

> Customers can access it by going to login.salesforce.com/one/one.app.
>   Once you log into login.salesforce.com/one/one.app you can then "pin
>   to start" and an icon will show up on the home/start screen. This will
>   look and feel similar to a downloadable app.

Here is an update from [Salesforce](https://success.salesforce.com/apex/ideaView?id=08730000000l2sIAAQ)(1 year back)

> Hi Everyone, quick update on this Idea:
>
> The downloadable container/app for Windows 8.1 is still in preview and
>   will stay in preview indefinitely as we are shifting our focus to
>   build an App for Windows 10, given MSFT's shift in focus shift here as
>   well.
>
> Mobile browser is available and is supported for Windows 8.1 phones
>   using IE11. Customers can access it by going to
>   login.salesforce.com/one/one.app. Once you log into
>   login.salesforce.com/one/one.app you can then "pin to start" and an
>   icon will show up on the home/start screen. This will look and feel
>   similar to a downloadable app.
>
> There is no difference in feature functionality between the mobile
>   browser for 8.1 and the downloadable app for 8.1 except for how the
>   app displays on the home/start screen. Once in the app the
>   functionality is the same.
>
> We hope to have a preview available for S1 for Windows 10 around
>   Dreamforce (safe harbor)